# Replace Markdown heading tags with custom in Python Markdown

Tags: python, markdown, python-markdown

We want to replace the default `h` tags, introduced by markdown using `#`, with a custom HTML Tag. For Parsing Markdown to HTML we use [the Python Library Markdown](https://pypi.org/project/Markdown/).

We have tried to register an extension that uses a H1 regex. This extension uses the regexp `(#) (.*)` for detecting H1 Elements.

```py
import markdown
from markdown.extensions import Extension
from markdown.inlinepatterns import SimpleTagPattern

class CustomHeadings(Extension):
    def extendMarkdown(self, md, md_globals):
        H1_RE = r'(#) (.*)'

        h1_tag = SimpleTagPattern(H1_RE, 'span class="h1"')
        md.inlinePatterns['h1'] = h1_tag

md_extensions = [CustomHeadings()]

# [...]

def ds_custom_markdown_parse(value):
    return markdown.markdown(value, extensions=md_extensions)
```

We want to have `h{1-6}` elements as a `span class="h{1-6}"`. But the Markdown parser still matches the string `# This is a h1` to `<h1>This is a h1</h1>`. We expect the output to be `<span class="h1">This is a h1</span>`

Comment: This is a complete aside, and you may not have control over this, but using real `<h1>` etc. tags is objectively _vastly better_ than using `<span class="h1">` etc. Semantics are important. There are lots of reasons, but accessibility is probably the biggest.

Comment: @Chris we considered that because it's way easier to implement and so on, but we chose to do it in another way for reasons such as only one H1 a page or so that user content won't interfere our own efforts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Headings are block-level elements and therefore are not parsed by `inlinePatterns.` Prior to running the `inlinePatterns`, Python-Markdown runs the [BlockParser](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/api/#blockparser), which converts all of the block-level elements of the document into an [ElementTree](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/api/#working_with_et) object. Each block-level element is then passed through the `inlinePatterns` one at a time and the the span-level elements are parsed.

For example, given your heading `# This is a h1`, the BlockParser has already converted it to an H tag `<h1>This is a h1</h1>` and the inlinePatterns only see the text content of that tag `This is a h1`.

You have a few options for addressing this:

1. You could override the `BlockProcessor`s which parse headings so that they create the elements you desire from the get-go.
2. Or you could leave the existing block parser in place and create a [TreeProcessor](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/api/#treeprocessors) which steps through the completed ElementTree object and alters the elements by redefining the tag names in the relevant elements.

Option 2 should be much simpler and is, in fact, the method used by a few existing extensions.

Full discloser: I am the lead developer of the Python-Markdown project.